# How to change language in the Bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, languages, moderncv

My header is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{bibgerm}

\moderncvtheme[red]{classic}
\usepackage[left=25mm,right=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}

\nopagenumbers{}                            

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\nocite{*}
\newpage
\section{Literatur}

\small{\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\bibliographyitemlabel{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xy}}

\end{document}
```

I want to include a Bibliography:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\bibliographyitemlabel{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xy}
```

But now, this bibliography is in English and I want to have it in German. The authors are separated by `and`, but it should be German (`und`).
So how to change the language in the Bibliography?

Even if I put 
`\bibliographystyle{gerplain}`
I get `und` instead of `and`, but then the first and surname are switched.

I tried the example below. Didn't work. So I try to put up an example of an entry in my bibfile:

```
@book{...,
author="... and ...",
title={{title}},
language="English",
publisher="{}",
year=""
}
@article{...,
author="... and ...",
title={{xyz.}},
language="English",
journal="...",
volume="",
number="",
pages="",
year=""
}
```

I just don't know what to do anymore. Tried all I could find while searching on google and other platforms.

Comment: Use the package `bibgerm` in combination with the German version of plain: `gerplain`.

Comment: So I changed to "bibgerm", but "gerplain" is not working. I get mistakes and prename and surname of the authors are in wrong position. What else can one do?

Comment: Not working? What do you mean? Please provide complete minimal working example.

Comment: So if I put "gerplain" I get the wanted ----und----

Comment: Oups: Only the first and surname of the FIRST AUTHOR are switched, separated by ","

Answer (score 2):

I do not have your `bib` file (update your question and add it please), so please test the following MWE by your own (on my systen it runs):

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68484/how-to-change-language-in-the-bibliography
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,ngerman]{moderncv}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\moderncvtheme[red]{classic}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{Strasse Hausnummer}{PLZ Ort}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\email{john@johndoe.de}
\homepage{www.johndoe.de}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\makecvtitle

\nocite{*}
\small{\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\bibliographyitemlabel{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother

\bibliographystyle{plaindin} % gerplain alphadin, plaindin, abbrvdin, unsrtdin
\bibliography{mybib}         % Literaturverzeichnis

\end{document}
```

I use the English (for literatur) and the German languages (German CV), see document class option, `babel` and `\selectlanguage`. I use the German bibliography style `plaindin` so I have not to load the rather old `bibgerm`.

I deleted the lines in your MWE which are not neccecary for a minimal working example and added some which were missing in your MWE.