# Bibliographystyle babelbib alpha.bst

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

For my document's bibliography, I use the `babelbib` package with the `alpha.bst` style and I create my bibliography like this:

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{literature/lit}
```

Now I'd like to modifiy it a little bit: For example, I get my authors formated like this

```
Michael A. Harrison, Walter L. Ruzzo, and Jeffrey D. Ullman.
```

At first I want the `and` to be the German `und` and at second I would like to remove the `,` before the final `and`.

I've read about changing this in my alpha.bst file but I could not figure out how exactly...

Comment: Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68484/124842 Is your question finaly solved with your answer?

Comment: No, I did'nt but editing my alpha.bst as described solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trouble, I could figure out a solution. Changing `" and "` to `" und "` was no problem. The comma issue was harder but could be solved by modifying the function `format.names`. I changed

```
        { numnames #2 >
            { "," * }
```

to

```
        { numnames #2 >
            { "" * }
```

which seems to be the correct solution.

---

EDIT: Here is a simple MWEB as requested.

```
\documentclass[oneside, openright, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{Harrison76,
        Title                    = {{Protection in Operating Systems}},
        Author                   = {Michael A. Harrison and Walter L. Ruzzo and Jeffrey D. Ullman},
        Journal                  = {Communications of the ACM},
        Year                     = {1976},

        Month                    = {August},
        Number                   = {8},
        Pages                    = {461--471},
        Volume                   = {19},

        Acmid                    = {360333},
        Address                  = {New York, NY, USA},
        Doi                      = {10.1145/360303.360333},
        ISSN                     = {0001-0782},
        Issue_date               = {Aug. 1976},
        Keywords                 = {turing machine, decidability, operating system, protection, protection system, security models, access control, HRU security model, safety},
        Numpages                 = {11},
        Publisher                = {ACM},
        Url                      = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/360303.360333}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    \cite{Harrison76}

    \bibliographystyle{alpha}
    \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

It is important that the alpha.bst is located in the same directory like the tex file. It contains the above mentioned changes.

Comment: Note that you should rename the `.bst` file if you edited it. Ideally you would also add a comment at the end that indicates what you changed, the date of change and your name. (IANAL, but this might even be required by the license of the `.bst` file.)