# Change language "and" on bibliography (BibTeX)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Currently, I'm using a custom bibliograph ystyle (I've made it with makebst before), in this case, I'm not going to change my bibliographystyle. My problem is on the language `and`. It should be `dan` (In Indonesian language).

Example:

> Polyanin, A. D., V. F. Zaitsev, **and** C. Mark

Becomes

> Polyanin, A. D., V. F. Zaitsev, **dan** C. Mark

Even if i use `\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}`, it didn't change anything.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[indonesian]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[bahasa, indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\begin{document}
    I am whatever . ajefanjak esgeajngkjnjkgnkaj
    \bibliography{bibliography}
    \bibliographystyle{unejstyle}
    \nocite{test}
\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib:

```
@book{test,
    author = {Polyanin, A. D. and V. F. Zaitsev and C. Mark},
    year = {2008},
    title = {Research Design: Qualitative, Quantitative, and Mixed Methods Approaches},
    edition = {Third},
    note = {Terjemahan oleh W. Gunawan. 1987. \textit{Peubah Kompleks untuk Ilmuwan dan Insinyur}. Jakarta: Erlangga.},
    address = {California},
    publisher = {Sage Publication}  
}
```

I've seen a possible duplicate [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68484), but got nothing from there.

Comment: You mention that you used the `makebst` utility to create a bespoke bibliography style file, `unejstyle.bst`. In that case, all you would need to do is copy the bst file to, say, `unejstyle-id.bst`, open the newly created bib style file in a text editor (the program you use to edit your tex files will do fine), search for the function `bbl.and`, and replace the string `"and"` with `"dan"`. While you're at it, you may want to check if any of the other `bbl.<xxx>` functions, where `<xxx>` could be `editor`, `editors`, `edby`, etc, may need to be adjusted as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\newcommand{\harvardand}{\HAR@and@dcu}
\renewcommand{\harvardand}{dan}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you indent your code by 4 spaces, the MarkDown formatter will present it as code and preserve newlines and indentations. // That said, I am not sure how your code is meant to be used, can you add a few more lines to clarify?